# Fluent API HasXXX vs WithXXX methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, extension-methods, ef-fluent-api

I am studying how to use fluent API from here:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

It says the following 1-Many relationships are the same thing:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
  .HasRequired<Standard>(s => s.Standard)
  .WithMany(std => std.Students)
  .HasForeignKey(std => std.StdId);
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Standard>()
  .HasMany<Student>(std => std.Students)
  .WithRequired(s => s.Standard)
  .HasForeignKey(s => s.StdId);
```

From intellisense, I noticed HasXXX methods return the target type and WithXXX methods return the parent type.

So I don't understand how the first approach is valid as HasForeignKey is applied to Standard and not Student?

The foreign key should be on Student and not Standard.

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the first one `modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasRequired<Standard>(s => s.Standard)` specifies that Student entity requires NotNull Standard navigation property and it return the `Standard` entity. Then you use `.WithMany(s => s.Students)`which specifies that the other side of Student (means Standard entity ) can include many `Students` in Students collection property.
2. For the second one, its straight forward. `modelBuilder.Entity<Standard>()` returns the `Standard` entity which can include many `Students` in Students collection property. So you have to use `.HasMany<Student>(std => std.Students)`. This will return Student entity and you have to define the constraint for that using `.HasMany<Student>(std => std.Students)`

Comment: Thanks but what I would like to know is in the first HasForeignKey(std => std.StdId) is applied to Standard and not Student. The foreign key should be on Student and not Standard.